# How to convert JAVA POJO class to Scala Case Class with SnakeCase

Tags: scala, pojo

In Scala, I am trying to convert from Java POJO class to Scala Case class. Please below find the details:

```
//Java POJO Response Class
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class IncidentResponse {
private String issueType;
private List<OrderDetailResponse> orderDetails;
//GETTER and SETTERs}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OrderDetailResponse {
private String orderId;
private String orderItemId;
//GETTER and SETTERs
public List<OrderDetailResponse> getOrderDetails() {return this.orderDetails;}}


//Scala Case Class
@JsonNaming(classOf[SnakeCaseStrategy])
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
case class IncidentDetails(issueType: String,
                           orderDetails: List[OrderDetailResponse]) 
//OrderDetailResponse is from the Scala Case Class

@JsonNaming(classOf[SnakeCaseStrategy])
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
case class OrderDetailResponse(orderId:String,
                               orderItemId:String)
```

I have tried the below ways to convert the data in SnakeCase -

Variable "data" contains the IncidentResponse of JAVA POJO Class

1. Using asInstanceof List[Map] and then using Object Mapper convert it to the OrderDetailResponse

`val orderDetails = data.getOrderDetails.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Any]]].map(p => (mapper.convertValue(p, typeReference[OrderDetailResponse](tTag)).asInstanceOf[OrderDetailResponse].get))
IncidentDetails(data.getIssueType,orderDetails)`

Got the error as - java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.List

2. Tried to convert List[Map[Object,Object]]:

   `val scalaList =data.getOrderDetails.asScala.toList.asInstanceOf[List[Map[Object,Object]]]
   IncidentDetails(data.getIssueType,
                   scalaList.asInstanceOf[List[OrderDetailResponse]])`

Didn't get any error with this, however it was not converted to SnakeCase of OrderDetailResponse but issueType was converted to SnakeCase

3. If i assign values individually from the POJO class then it will work, if I have many fields then it will leads to many lines of code so how to convert to SnakeCase of Scala case class from Java POJO class.

   `IncidentDetails(data.getIssueType,
                   data.getOrderDetails.asScala.head.map(orderResp => 
                   OrderDetailResponse(orderResp.getOrderId,orderResp.getOrderItemId)
                   )`